# In Laravel, how to simply pass data from js to controller back to view?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I basically need to click a button in my blade view that triggers a function in my js file, that then sends some values to a controller and back to the the view. Using the code below, do I need to be creating a route for this? Thanks

```
view:
<div id="sendAsEmailTest">SEND AS EMAIL TEST</div>


js:
$('#sendAsEmailTest').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
    type: "POST",
    url: "FormController/TestFunction",
    data: { name: "John" }
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    // alert( "Data Saved: " + msg.name );
  });
});


FormController:
public function TestFunction(Request $request)
     {
       return view('calculator.calculator',
         [
         'testdata' => $request,
         ]
       );
     }
```

Comment: basic solution, use ajax.. best solution use Livewire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your route should be post

```
route::post('formController/testfunction'@'FormController@TestFunction')
```

just

```
 public function TestFunction(Request $request)
         {
         dd($request->name)<---- you get your attribute  value here
         }
then correct
```

js:

```
$('#sendAsEmailTest').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
    type: "POST",
    url: "formController/testfunction",<------------------all letters in small
    data: { name: "John" }
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    // alert( "Data Saved: " + msg.name );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the help @ßãlãjî. had to adjust things slightly, but seems to be working fine now:

```
js:
$('#sendAsEmailTest').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
    type: "POST",
    url: "/formControllertestfunction",
    data: { name: "John" }
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    // alert( "Data Saved: " + msg.name );
  });
});

route:
Route::post('formControllertestfunction','FormController@TestFunction')->name('formControllertestfunction');

controller:
public function TestFunction(Request $request) {
         return view('calculator.back',
           [
             'displayName' => $request->name ,
           ]);
       }
```